# Помогите пожалуйста! Как узнать логин и пароль от почты через python?

Tags: python, email, пароль, логин

Я не знаю как добыть пароль и логин от почты через python.
Представляю что можно зайти в настройки и в безопасности найти там лог пасс но не могу это реализовать.
В инете искал ничего не нашел

Comment: От какой почты, где? Почему вы думаете, что питон это сможет?

Comment: Вроде в python можно делать вставки на С? может на нем получиться?

Comment: @BorvitQwerty а как вставки на С помогут вам получить логин и пароль от почты?

Comment: А разве нельзя расшифровать данные из страницы безопасности брузера? Всм в настройках безопасности есть

Comment: Ну, зайдите и посмотрите ваш пароль в настройках безопасности, зачем вам Python для этого?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

То что вы описали называется стиллер. Все сохраненные пользователем данные для входа хранятся в не очень зашифрованном виде в локальной базе данных обозревателя (браузера).

Более подробно изучить работу стиллера вы можете покопавшись в этом репозитории: [www.github.com/hakanonymos/steal-chrome-password-all-version/](http://www.github.com/hakanonymos/steal-chrome-password-all-version/)

И помните что несанкционированный доступ к личным данным является не законным и противоправным деянием. Не используйте стиллер в корыстных целях

Comment: Большое спасибо! :D

Comment: @BorvitQwerty если мой ответ помог, то пожалуйста отметьте его как решение (галочкой). Рад был помочь :)

Comment: Отметил. Большое спасибо)

Comment: Можно вас попросить скинуть ваш телеграмм или вк? У меня есть ещё вопрос, но он настолько тупой, что мне стыдно опубликовывать его здесь.

Answer (score -2):

Способов раздобыть пароль и логин электронной почты достаточно.
Фишинг - реализуем, при помощи библиотеки requests, знаний языка php и умении верстки, скриптинга страниц.
Подробнее: https://forumteam.top/threads/sozdaem-fishingovyj-sajt-s-nulja.9069/
Стиллер - библиотеки  os, requests, другие и соц. инженерия.
Подробнее: https://lolz.guru/threads/1644614/
Брутфорс - также, requests, при помощи post-запросов. Подробнее: https://lolz.guru/threads/2290295/